# SSH over VPN confusion

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, vnc

I have a small question that I haven't really figured out.
I have a Raspberry Pi in the dorm room of my university to which I want SSH access to (or, better said, VNC connection but that shouldn't make the difference.) from home.

We do have VPN access to the campus. (How) is it possible to SSH into the Pi from the Laptop at home? Is the local IP I see with my Laptop through the VPN my actual local address or is it the local IP on the campus then?
I'm a little confused about this, Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need to foward the port to your RPi.  I assume you don't have the ability to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that's not possible. At least the usual setup is to have the dorm-clients (and the faculty, ...) in separate networks. VPN only gets you in the part of the network where the servers live. Likewise, the client/dorm-network wouldn't have access to the VPN client network but only to the server net.

In case your university handles that differently: You need to know the IP address of your raspberry. And you need to know, if that changes. If they don't, you can try connecting to that address from home, after you're dialed in via VPN. If they do, you'll need to find a way to be informed of new IP addresses, like having your raspberry mail them to you.

Comment: That's rather annoying. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes. Rent a VPN somewhere, set up OpenVPN or something like it and connect both your raspberry and your computer at home to it. But that's less annoying, yet harder because you'll have to learn networking.

Comment: Yet another way is to hire chip *nix based VDS in the internet to set up a pair of ssh tunnels (or OpenVPN) from your PI to be able to connect via that VDS from home.
Issue `ssh -fNR 5000:127.0.0.1:22  user@your_vds_IP` from your PI, and connect to VDS from your laptop with `ssh -fNL 5000:127.0.0.1:5000 user@your_vds_IP`. After that you will be able to connect to your PI from Laptop using just `ssh 127.0.0.1:5000`.